# Set java environment variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have set my java environment variables as described:

under System variables i have the following:

Variable : `JAVA_HOME` and the values for this as : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80`

and the variable '`path`' i have added the same file path as that  of `JAVA_HOME` that is : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80`

but when i check my java version from command prompt it shows: java version `1.8.0_152`.

what am in doing wrong. I have both jdk `1.8` and `1.7` installed in my machine. I am working on windows 10 - 64 bit machine

Comment: Check if you have several Java paths using command `set path` in command line.

Comment: You also need to set variable PATH as  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin

Comment: Update your path variable, path should be till bin directory

Comment: @Susanna Michael Are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. i did try changing that. Didn't work. So i went ahead and uninstalled my java 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the variable path till `bin` directory

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
PATH      : %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

**Explanation**

To compile and run a `java` program we use `javac` and `java` commands.But these commands are unknown to your `OS` until we explicitly specify the location of these executable files. This is the main reason why we need to set path in Java and while specifying the path we specify the path of `bin` folder which contains the executable files.